# Whether the PAC file supports loops?

Tags: proxy, pac

I have PAC file

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
 if (shExpMatch(host, "*site1*"))
  return 'socks5 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx';
 else if (shExpMatch(host, "*site2*"))
  return 'socks5 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx';
 else
  return "DIRECT"
}
```

how this do in loop f.e. foreach loop or for loop